# Making surface plot of regression estimates from multiple continuous variables

Tags: r, plot, model, surface

I have a multi-level model with categorical and continuous variables and splines. Nice and complex. Anyhow I am trying to visualize model fit.

For example, here is some toy data:

```
library(lme4)
library(rms)
library(gridExtra)

## Make model using sleepstudy data
head(sleepstudy)
# Add some extra vars
sleepstudy$group <- factor( sample(c(1,2), nrow(sleepstudy), replace=TRUE) )
sleepstudy$x1 <- jitter(sleepstudy$Days, factor=5)^2 * jitter(sleepstudy$Reaction)

# Set up a mixed model with spline
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ rcs(Days, 4) * group + (rcs(Days, 4) | Subject), sleepstudy)
# Now add continuous covar
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ rcs(Days, 4) * group + x1 + (rcs(Days, 4) | Subject), sleepstudy)

# Plot fit
new.df <- sleepstudy
new.df$pred1 <- predict(fm1, new.df, allow.new.levels=TRUE, re.form=NA)
new.df$pred2 <- predict(fm2, new.df, allow.new.levels=TRUE, re.form=NA)

g1 <- ggplot(data=new.df, aes(x=Days)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=pred1, col=group), size=2) +
    ggtitle("Model 1")
g2 <- ggplot(data=new.df, aes(x=Days)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=pred2, col=group), size=2) +
    ggtitle("Model 2")

 grid.arrange(g1, g2, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Plot 1 is smooth, but plot 2 is jagged due to the effect of x1. So I would like to make a surface plot with `x = Days`, `y = x1` and `z = pred2` and stratified by `group`. Not having experience of surface plots I've started out with the wireframe command:

```
wireframe(pred2 ~ Days * x1, data = new.df[new.df$group==1,],
      xlab = "Days", ylab = "x1", zlab="Predicted fit"
)
```

However although this command does not give an error, my plot is blank:

[image]

## Questions:

1. Where am I going wrong with my wireframe?
2. Is there a better way to visualize my model fit?

Comment: I am getting same result using (nothing) from `plotly::plot_ly`.

Comment: You don't have a surface. That's the problem. Your data has single points at x,y,z. Look at the data `volcano` to figure out what can be represented as a surface. At best you can have a 3d line.

Comment: So, how would u suggest I visulise these regression coefficients ?

Comment: First of all I suggest that `X1` is not correlated with prediction. Second by looking at `rgl::plot3d(mydf$Days, mydf$x1, mydf$pred2)` you may get some ideas about visualization. p.s. `mydf <- new.df[new.df$group==1,]`.

Comment: Yeah i just made x1 as quick as possible for a reproducible demo, but in my real data the variable is correlated.

Comment: I may be able to help you further if I can take a look at the real data; however, Idk if you can release all the data. `plotly::plot_ly(data, x = ~Days, y = ~x1, z = ~pred2, type = 
    'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', opacity = 1
               , line = list(width = 6, color = "red", reverscale = FALSE))` You may find this helpful as well.

Comment: Ha no can't do that. But thanks for the tips.

Comment: I modified x1 to be related to both Days & Reaction. Its now more representative of my real data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the data format needed for a `wireframe' or`plot_ly' surface is that of a 2D matrix of x rows by y columns of corresponding z values (I got a hint towards this from this question [Plotly 3d surface graph has incorrect x and y axis values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576455/plotly-3d-surface-graph-has-incorrect-x-and-y-axis-values?rq=1)). I also realised I could use `expand.grid' to make a matrix covering the range of possible x and y values and use those to predict z as follows:

```
days <- 0:9
x1_range <- range(sleepstudy$x1)[2] * c(0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3)

new.data2 <- expand.grid(Days = days, x1 = x1_range, group = unique(sleepstudy$group) )
new.data2$pred <- predict(fm2, new.data2, allow.new.levels=TRUE, re.form=NA)
```

I can then stuff those into two different matrices to represent the z-surface for each group in my model:

```
surf1 <- ( matrix(new.data2[new.data2$group == 1, ]$pred, nrow = length(days), ncol = length(x1_range)) )
surf2 <- ( matrix(new.data2[new.data2$group == 2, ]$pred, nrow = length(days), ncol = length(x1_range)) )
group <- c(rep(1, nrow(surf1)), rep(2, nrow(surf2) ))
```

Finally I can use plot_ly to plot each surface:

```
plot_ly (z=surf1, x = mets_range, y = ages, type="surface") %>%
    add_surface (z = surf2, surfacecolor=surf2,
             color=c('red','yellow'))
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

So the resulting plot is what I wanted (albeit not very useful in this made up example but useful in real data). The only thing I can't figure out is how to show two different color scales. I can suppres the scale altogether but if anyone knows how to show 2 scales for different surfaces do please let me know and I will edit the answer.